# Disk ID in chroot / jail

Tags: hard-disk, udev, chroot

When I print out all information about a disk /dev/sda on my host system, then I get this sort of information (I got this information with command udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda):

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
N: sda
S: disk/by-id/ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VB8cef94cd-f15e891d
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VB8cef94cd-f15e891d
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sda
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
E: DEVTYPE=disk
E: ID_ATA=1
E: ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_PM=1
E: ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_PM_ENABLED=1
E: ID_ATA_SATA=1
E: ID_ATA_SATA_SIGNAL_RATE_GEN2=1
E: ID_ATA_WRITE_CACHE=1
E: ID_ATA_WRITE_CACHE_ENABLED=1
E: ID_BUS=ata
E: ID_MODEL=VBOX_HARDDISK
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=VBOX\x20HARDDISK\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
E: ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
E: ID_REVISION=1.0
E: ID_SERIAL=VBOX_HARDDISK_VB8cef94cd-f15e891d
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=VB8cef94cd-f15e891d
E: ID_TYPE=disk
E: MAJOR=8
E: MINOR=0
E: MPATH_SBIN_PATH=/sbin
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=18821
```

But in chroot / jail, typing the same command, I get:

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
N: sda
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sda
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
E: DEVTYPE=disk
E: MAJOR=8
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
```

I mounted the following folders into jail:

```
sudo mount -t proc /proc/ /target/proc
sudo mount -t sysfs /sys/ /target/sys
sudo mount --bind /dev/ /target/dev
```

What am I missing, to get all needed information about my hard disk /dev/sda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `strace udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda` I could see that `/run/udev/data/b8:0` is also read:

```
open("/run/udev/data/b8:0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

This is an ASCII file:

```
/run/udev/data/b8:0: ASCII text
```

Containing the information you want to see.

In your case it is necessary to have `/run/udev/data` available in your chroot environment aswell to run the `udevadm` command